# Cron job to send push notifications

Tags: php, push-notification, cron, onesignal

I'm looking for the most solid solution for this scenario:

Server 1 serves a XML updated every 15 seconds (or less) with live sport events (this like goals, halftime, match end).

I'm using OneSignal API to send push notifications to the users of my App (iOS and Android) each time the XML brings something new.

So, what would be better?:

- A cron job with a PHP file, reading the XML and triggering the push notifications when there's something new?
- Something like Node will be better?

The thing that makes me worry is that if the cron job runs every, say, 10 seconds, it may fail sooner or latter.

So, anyone can advise in the most solid solution to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: cron job  is best one

Comment: Think of something else like queuing services or message-queue -- like iron.io, rabbitMQ, Gearman, etc. Crons are good for simple schedules - there are limited options for setting a cron and they will not depend on other tasks to be completed.

Comment: @HimelNagRana That's a good advice. I'm going to look up for services like iron.io. Something maybe not too expensive...

Answer (score 0):

The cron itself cannot do what you want to do. You can create your own routine. The use of sleep (but this will not give the correct results, as it does not take into account the time required to run the command).

Cron only allows for a **minimum of one minute**. 

 You can consider writing a shell script with an infinite loop that runs your task, and then sleeps for x seconds, but as I said before is not accurate.

**Edit:**
Here you can see how to make a shell script [link1](https://serverfault.com/questions/141031/cron-how-can-i-create-a-cronjob-that-runs-every-15-seconds)

Comment: Assuming it doesn't matter very much precisely when the routine runs, and it's not serious if two instances of the code are running concurrently, it's OK to run four different scripts at 1-minute intervals using cron. Each script has a different sleep time, between 0 and 45 seconds, before actually doing what it needs to do.

Comment: Well, the precision is kind of important because I can't have the same push notification sent to the same users more than once... I didn't knew about that one minute minimum...